# Stencil Component has zero dimension

Tags: stenciljs

in my Stenciljs component, I check the size of the element in the componentDidLoad method.  This works correct, if the page is reloaded in the browser.  But when I move there from another page, the dimension is always 0 x 0.

How can I get the correct element dimension even during or after page navigation?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It might be a bug with the rendering queue, but I'm not sure. Anyway, you could use a recursive approach with `requestAnimationFrame` to wait until your element has rendered with a width and height.

```js
componentDidLoad() {
  const checkSize = () => {
    const el = document.querySelector('my-element');

    if (!el.offsetWidth && !el.offsetHeight) {
      return requestAnimationFrame(checkSize);
    }

    // if we get here, `el` has a width or height
  }

  checkSize();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, `componentDidLoad` is bit to early sometimes if you want to check size of a element because elements are on the page but browser did not yet set their size.

Best approach is to try to make [flexible](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) elements and allow them to adjust themself.
Also consider [css grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/).

If by some reason you still cannot rely on that solution, try [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/What-is-document-ready-equivalent-in-JavaScript):

```
 const loader = setInterval(()=> {
  if(document.readyState !== 'complete') return;
  clearInterval(loader);
  //HERE I WOULD CHECK SIZE
}, 150);
```

I know this is ugly and I would like to know better solution too :)

Comment: Well, grids and flexboxes are no solution here.  I do have to programatically position an image such that the important part of the image is visible regardless of the size and ratio of the element.  The image may be larger and hidden outside the box.  So I have to calculate the top and left position.